# How can I override an inherited object's property in the constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, properties, pixi.js

I'm trying to create a new Object by inheriting pixi.js's PIXI.Container object. The PIXI.Container object has the properties height and width, which I would like to set from the parameters of my constructor. Every time I attempt to do so, the 'this.height' parameter is always 0.

I'm so confused!

```
var Chunk = function(data) {

console.log(data);

/*
*   Outputs:
*   Object {
*     "_id": "555f7939c3ae58523f63b847",
*     "x": 2,
*     "y": 2,
*     "height": 2000,
*     "width": 2000,
*     "__v": 0,
*     "layers": [
*       {
*         "name": "collision",
*         "height": 2000,
*         "width": 2000,
*         "opacity": 1,
*         "visible": true,
*         "type": "objectgroup",
*         "objects": []
*       }
*     ]
*   }
*/

PIXI.Container.call(this);

console.log(this);

/*
*   Outputs:
*   Couldn't copy the object, but i've included a link to a working
*   demo where you can see it output. https://vast-wildwood-6251.herokuapp.com/
*/

this.height = data.height;
this._width = data.width;
this.coords = {
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y
};
this.x = data.x * this._width;
this.y = data.y * this.height;
console.log(this.height); // Outputs: 0
this.planets = [];

var border = new PIXI.Graphics();
border.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000, 1);
border.drawRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
this.addChild(border);

for (var c = 0; c < data.layers.length; c++) {
    for (var o = 0; o < data.layers[c].objects.length; o++) {
        var planet = new Planet(data.layers[c].objects[o]);
        game.planets.push(planet);
        this.planets.push(planet);
        this.addChild(planet.graphics);
    }
}

};

Chunk.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Container.prototype);

Chunk.prototype.constructor = Chunk;
```

Made an edit as requested.

Also, here's a link to a working demo of the code, and a link to the github repo

https://vast-wildwood-6251.herokuapp.com/
https://github.com/storrdev/delta-wing

Comment: Please add more `console.log()` in the start and output the `data` object and `this` object after applying `PIXI.Container.call(this);` . Also please add lines of the constuctor call - to see the whole picture. Maybe you've forgot something.

Comment: I've made the changes you've requested. Thanks for the help. I was unable to copy the output of the "this" object to the clipboard without losing information, so I just attached a demo where you can inspect the objects for real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `PIXI.Container` uses a setter for the `height` property. Therefore, you can't set it directly. See https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/blob/master/src/core/display/Container.js#L78

```
Object.defineProperties(Container.prototype, {    
    /**
     * The height of the Container, setting this will actually modify the scale to achieve the value set
     *
     * @member {number}
     * @memberof PIXI.Container#
     */
    height: {
        get: function ()
        {
            return  this.scale.y * this.getLocalBounds().height;
        },
        set: function (value)
        {

            var height = this.getLocalBounds().height;

            if (height !== 0)
            {
                this.scale.y = value / height ;
            }
            else
            {
                this.scale.y = 1;
            }

            this._height = value;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

I've gone back and changed the line "this.height = data.height" to "this.height.set(data.height)" and get an error: "this.height.set" is not a function. I'm still confused as to how I can set the height of this object in the constructor.

Comment: @saoyr5 There's not `set`, the setter gets called when you do `this.height = data.height` and the setter can prevent you from setting the height, if it choses to do so, which is what it looks like it's doing. You can see that the getter (what gets called when you read `this.height`) actually doesn't even use that value to return the height. You should debug it and step into the setter and getter from `PIXI.container`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me.

It looks like setting this.height allows me to access that value using this._height... Since it's just a reference to my game and not the PIXI library, I'm fine with that.